# What is the second parameter for in the function glVertexAttribPointer?

Tags: opengl

In the function `glVertexAttribPointer`, what is the second argument for (the ***size*** parameter)? In the vertex shader, it gets input from the VAO using: `layout (location = 0) in vec2 pos;` Why would we need to define the size of the vertex attribute if it gets input a certain amount. If it is a vec2, it can only get input 2 numbers. Why would we need to define the size then?

Answer (score 2):

VAOs are not directly attached to shaders. As such, the two interfaces (the VAO providing data and the shader consuming it) do not have to be in exact alignment.

If a VAO attribute provides more data than the shader consumes, that is fine; it just means that some data is wasted. You can pass 4 values to an attribute that expects 2.

If a VAO attribute provides *less* data than the shader consumes, that's also fine. The unfilled data gets filled in by zeros, except for the last value which will be 1.0. Note that if the VAO disables a particular attributes that the shader uses, it will [get values from the default attribute vectors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Non-array_attribute_values). (note: please do not use these in real code)

Also, in more recent GL versions, shaders get to [mess around with how the components of input values from a VAO are assigned to input variables](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interface_components). A VAO attribute can send 4 values, but you can split them into multiple variables:

```
layout(location = 0, component = 0) vec2 firstTwo;
layout(location = 0, component = 2) float third;
layout(location = 0, component = 3) float fourth;
```

This funnels the first two components into one `vec2`, with the last two components each being assigned to `float`s.